# Changing the width of the columns of the bookmarks display?

Tags: bookmarks

I love the bookmarks features of Emacs.  I have managed my bookmarks kind of hierarchic.  But that leads to longer bookmarks, which now don't fit into the column any more.

Is there a way, to enlarge the first column of the bookmark display buffer?

Comment: Take a look at `M-x customize-group bookmark` to see if there is an option for it.

Comment: @xuchunyang Thank you.  I still have to become acustomed to the `M-x customize` thing.  There is a field `Bookmar Bmenu File column`, that I increased.  Would you please give your comment as answet.  I would love to give you the green "solved" mark!

Comment: You can set `bookmark-bmenu-file-column` in your `.emacs` file, like this `(setq bookmark-bmenu-file-column 41)`.

Comment: I don't use bookmark. Please write an answer and accept it since you know the exact answer.

Comment: @xuchunyang but you deserve the credit and the honor.

Answer (score 2):

As explained in the comments on the question, you can change the width of the bookmark name column by adding this line to your `init.el`:

```
 (setq bookmark-bmenu-file-column 50)
```

Or you can use Customize:

1. Type `M-x cu-var RET bo-b-f-c RET`
2. Edit the **Bookmark Bmenu File Column** field.
3. Click **Apply And Save.**

Note you have to kill and relaunch the Bookmark List buffer before you can see your changes.